# MYSQL node js insert issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

Please help, why this code doesn't work?

```
let [phones, computers, numbers, accessories, smartwatches] = cat;
let names = ["phones", "computers", "numbers", "accessories", "smartwatches"];

for (let i=0; i<names.length; i++){

  let sql = `"INSERT INTO cat (name) VALUES( ${names[i]})" `;

  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Records inserted");

  });

  connection.query( "DELETE n1 FROM cat n1, cat n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name");
}
```

This is an error message:
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO cat (name) VALUES( phones)"' at line 1

---

when i wrote this without loop, it inserts data in one id(field) all the items in names array. How can I change it?

---

I change some things but now I have another error. Look at this:

```
let [phones, computers, numbers, accessories, smartwatches] = cat;
let names = ["phones", "computers", "numbers", "accessories", "smartwatches"];
for (let i=0; i<names.length; i++){
let nameses = names[i];
  let obj = {"name":"",
              "url":""};
  obj["name"] = nameses;
  obj['url']=cat[i];
  console.log(obj);
  let sql = ("INSERT INTO cat SET?", obj ) ;
connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
  console.log("Records inserted");
 });


connection.query( "DELETE n1 FROM cat n1, cat n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name");
```

Now error is : Query is empty but when I console.log the obj - it gives me the the correct result with key and value of object. Why mysql thinks that is empty? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you using prepared statements? When creating dynamic SQL statements I find it easy to maintain if I keep a consistent naming and escaping routine for my statements.

For example the SQL keywords; INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, WHERE, JOIN, OR & AND should be capitalized where database, table and field names are lowercase and wrapped with back ticks (i.e. `table_name`) and any field values are used as parameters in the statement and thus quoted in such a way to help with SQL injection attack vectors

`let sql = 'INSERT INTO`cat`(`name`) VALUES(?)';
connection.query(sql, ${names[i]}, function(err,  result){ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

`` `INSERT INTO cat (name) VALUES( ${names[i]})` ``

I think your double quotes are redundant

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the code in phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench or something like that - you are missing quotes around the values that should be inserted.

This could work:

```
let sql = `"INSERT INTO cat (name) VALUES( '${names[i]}')" `;
```

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO cat (name) VALUES( 'phones')"' at line 1

Comment: In your initial code, you have backticks and double quotes - what happens if you remove them in a pair, eg. through deleting both double quotes?

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. However, my downvote is to highlight that there is a scope to every question.